# ES Lint throwing no-unused-vars error on constructor variable

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a component that looks like this:

```
class NavPane extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let lastX = 0;
  }
  NavOnTouchStart = (e) => {
    this.lastX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  }
  NavOnTouchMove = (e) => {
    const currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    if (currentX > this.lastX + 10) {
      this.props.toggle();
    }
    this.lastX = currentX;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Collapse
        ...
      </Collapse>
    );
  }
}

export default onClickOutside(NavPane);
```

This runs fine when executed but ES Lint doesn't seem to agree. It keeps throwing the following error on the variable **lastX**:

> 21:9   error  'lastX' is assigned a value but never used 
>   no-unused-vars

Could someone help me understand what's going on here? I do realize that **let** and **const** are scoped to the block the variable is defined in which is why it's throwing an error since I'm not *using* it within the constructor. However, ES Lint also cribs when I use **var** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.lastX = 0;
  }
```